# Python3: how to detect if /dev/shm (or ProcessPoolPexecutor) can be used?

Tags: python-3.x

I have some code that gets improvement from being multi-processed, however in AWS Lambda, `/dev/shm` is not available so `ProcessPoolExecutor` fail with the cryptic error message:

```
 File "/var/task/black.py", line 529, in reformat_many
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=worker_count)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 556, in __init__
    pending_work_items=self._pending_work_items)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 165, in __init__
    super().__init__(max_size, ctx=ctx)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 67, in Lock
    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 59, in __init__
    unlink_now)
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

is there a portable way to detect that it would have failed ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a try/except with your exception : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: it would be the "pythonic" way. If you don't know if you can, try and apologize if needed.